# Different running time for cublasSetMatrix on similar matrices

Tags: cuda, gpu, gpgpu, nvidia

In the following code I'm using the function cublasSetMatrix for 3 random matrices of size 200x200. I measured the the time of this function in the code:

```
clock_t t1,t2,t3,t4;
int  m =200,n = 200;

float * bold1 = new float [m*n];

float * bold2 = new float [m*n];

float * bold3 = new float [m*n];

for (int i = 0; i< m; i++)

        for(int j = 0; j <n;j++)

                {

                        bold1[i*n+j]=rand()%10;

                        bold2[i*n+j]=rand()%10;

                        bold3[i*n+j]=rand()%10;

                }

float * dev_bold1, * dev_bold2,*dev_bold3;

cudaMalloc ((void**)&dev_bold1,sizeof(float)*m*n);

cudaMalloc ((void**)&dev_bold2,sizeof(float)*m*n);

cudaMalloc ((void**)&dev_bold3,sizeof(float)*m*n);

t1=clock();

cublasSetMatrix(m,n,sizeof(float),bold1,m,dev_bold1,m);

t2 = clock();

cublasSetMatrix(m,n,sizeof(float),bold2,m,dev_bold2,m);

t3 = clock();

cublasSetMatrix(m,n,sizeof(float),bold3,m,dev_bold2,m);

t4 = clock();

cout<<double(t2-t1)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC<<" - "<<double(t3-t2)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC<<" - "<<double(t4-t3)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

delete []bold1;

delete []bold2;

delete []bold3;

cudaFree(dev_bold1);

cudaFree(dev_bold2);

cudaFree(dev_bold3);
```

The output of this code is something like this:

> 0.121849 - 0.000131 - 0.000141

Actually, every time I run the code the time of applying cublasSetMatrix on the first matrix is more than other two matrices, although the size of all matrices are the same and they are filled with random numbers.

Can anyone please help me to find out what is the reason of this result?

Comment: If you do not call a synchronize method, you are only measuring the time it takes to *launch* the function. The operation is not necessarily completed. The first operation is much slower because the driver is either warming up or compiling some cuda kernels on the fly to the proper binary format.

Comment: It's most likely part of cublas library start-up overhead.  Are these the first cublas calls in your code?  Your code probably also has a cublas handle initialization.  Try moving that handle initialization to a point before these cublasSetMatrix calls, then see if the timing changes.

Comment: @RobertCrovella I used handle initialization before cublasSetMatrix, now all running times are very similar. Please write your comment as the answer so I can mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: There is a good tool for measuring time spent on every function -  NSIGHT. Try to use it, it will give you more detailed and correct information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually the first CUDA API call in any CUDA program will incur some start-up overhead - the CUDA runtime requires time to initialize everything.

Whenever CUDA libraries are used, there will be some additional one-time start up overhead associated with initialization of the library.  This overhead will often be observed to impact the timing of the first library call.

That seems to be what is happening here.  By placing *another* cuBLAS API call before the first one you are measuring, you have moved the start-up overhead cost to a previous call, and so you don't measure it on the `cublasSetMatrix()` call anymore.